# I need QGIS routing plug-in

Tags: qgis, pgrouting, routing

I am new to pgrouting. How does it work? What benefits can I get from it? I tried the examples, read some articles, but could not find the QGIS routing plugin for Windows.
It is not showing up in the plug-in manager. Finding a route in a given dataset by mentioning a start and end node works, but it is not performing on my local road network shapefile. The query executes, but doesn't show any results.

Also it says

> Postgres with PostGIS and pgAdmin
>   QGIS with PostGIS Manager and RT Sql Layer plugins

I don't find PostGIS Manager and RT Sql Layer plugins. Have seen osm2po articles, how do they work? What do I do next?

Comment: A lot of the questions you ask are perhaps answered in the documentation of the respective libraries you're interested in. I would highly recommend you start with [a pgrouting workshop](http://2011.foss4g.org/sessions/foss4g-routing-pgrouting-tools-openstreetmap-road-data-and-geoext)

Comment: Do you have the road shapefile loaded into PostGIS? Does pgRouting work if you execute queries in pgAdmin? Please read up on the topic and clarify your question: http://underdark.wordpress.com/tag/pgrouting

Comment: -1 from me, sorry. The (IMHO) sloppy spelling is just part of the reason. What's worse is that you're asking many questions all at once (and, IMHO, many of them are somewhat hazy), which makes it unclear what you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question(s) correctly, you can try RoadGraph plugin for QGIS, you might find it simpler to use, no need for DB, pgrouting etc. Here is longer description, sorry it is originally in Russian, autotranslated: http://bit.ly/A5CLgg